# Flutter - whitespaces displaying for image in portrait and landscape

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, singlechildscrollview

I keep seeing  lot of white space if I do landscape or portrait within my image. I do need the slidable so didn't want to tweak the code too much, but I do want it to look representable

is there something wrong with my code?

I did add a picture this is happening in both landscape and portrait mode

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rx8Gs.jpg]

[image: portrait image]

```
  @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(
                title: new Text(
                  "1 Alif-laam-meem آلم, Pg2",
                  style: new TextStyle(color: styling.appBarTextcolor),
                ),
                leading: new IconButton(
                    icon: new Icon(styling.appBarBackArrowIcon),
                    onPressed: () {
                      Navigator.push(
                          context,
                          MaterialPageRoute(
                            builder: (context) => NavDrawer(),
                          ));
                    })),
            body: LayoutBuilder(builder:
                (BuildContext context, BoxConstraints viewportConstraints) {
              return SingleChildScrollView(
                  child: Stack(children: <Widget>[
                new Slidable(
                  delegate: new SlidableDrawerDelegate(),
                  actionExtentRatio: styling.sizeofenglishandforward,
                  child: SafeArea(
                    top: true,
                    bottom: true,
                    right: true,
                    left: true,
                    child: new Container(
                      child: new Image.asset(
                        "test/assets/Para 1 - Alif-laam-meem no color/quranpg2-1.png",
                        // fit: BoxFit.fitidth,
                        fit: BoxFit.cover,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  actions: <Widget>[
                    new IconSlideAction(
                        caption: styling.englishIconText,
                        color: styling.englishIconColorstripe,
                        icon: styling.englishIcon,
                        foregroundColor: styling.englishIconColor,
                        onTap: () {
                          Navigator.push(
                            context,
                            MaterialPageRoute(
                                builder: (context) => Changepg2topg2Color()),
                          );
                        }),
                    new IconSlideAction(
                      caption: styling.forwardIconText,
                      color: styling.forwardIconColorstripe,
                      icon: styling.forwardIcon,
                      foregroundColor: styling.forwardIconColor,
                      // onTap: () {
                      //   Navigator.push(
                      //     context,
                      //     MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Changepg2topg3()),
                      // );
                      // }
                    ),
                    // ),
                  ],
                  secondaryActions: <Widget>[
                    new IconSlideAction(
                      caption: styling.backIconText,
                      color: styling.backIconColorstripe,
                      icon: styling.backIcon,
                      foregroundColor: styling.backIconColor,
                      // onTap: () => _showSnackBar('More'),
                    ),
                    new IconSlideAction(
                      caption: styling.arabicIconText,
                      color: styling.arabicIconColorstripe,
                      icon: styling.arabicIcon,
                      foregroundColor: styling.arabicIconColor,
                      // onTap: () =>
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ]));
            }));
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SafeArea` is preventing your image to go at some restricted areas of screen like, underneath the notch area. Or for some devices there are `NavigationKeys` in the bottom of screen. Try removing these

Cheers :)

```
child: SafeArea(
            top: true,
            bottom: true,
            right: true,
            left: true,
```

Comment: Thank you Hamza,  I changed the safe area value of true to false and its working :) for portrait mode . But when I do it in Landscape mode I still see lot of white space ill update the image

Comment: You are using `SafeArea` try removing it. If it works, then i think the prevention from Notches and Bottom navigations keys are `True` in it. Give it a shot :)

Comment: Hi I did try removing safeArea it is working for Portrait but not landscape.. is there anything else I can do?

Comment: I think there might be some dimensional issues with the image. Otherwise these were the possible solutions that I could think off :(

Comment: brother I need help with this one if you have time https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64548263/flutter-how-to-disable-switch-within-the-settings-menu-and-how-to-ensure-no-de