# Flutter - How to ensure the switch is on even after clicking on the back button?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

I have a settings menu with 8 listTiles and If I turn on one of the switches, the issue is -  when I click on the back button and click on the settings menu again, the switch is turned off ... what would I have to add to make sure the switch is on even if the back button is clicked?

After this- what ever switch is turned on that's the color image I want to display in another class ..... that is why I need to ensure only one switch is on at one time, and that once the user clicks the back button and clicks back into the setting page the switch is still turned on ... How can I go about doing these two things?

[image]

```
import 'dart:ui';
import 'package:Quran_highlighter/Widgets/styling.dart';
import 'package:adobe_xd/adobe_xd.dart';
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:Quran_highlighter/main.dart';
import 'package:flutter/rendering.dart';
import 'package:system_shortcuts/system_shortcuts.dart';
import 'package:Quran_highlighter/Widgets/NavDrawer.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:zoom_widget/zoom_widget.dart';
import 'package:flutter/gestures.dart';
import 'package:Quran_highlighter/Widgets/size_config.dart';
import 'package:flutter_slidable/flutter_slidable.dart';
import 'package:flutter_settings_screens/flutter_settings_screens.dart';
import 'package:peek_and_pop/misc.dart' as PeekAndPopMisc;
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

class SettingsMenu extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SettingsMenuState createState() => _SettingsMenuState();
}

// body: ListView.builder(
// itemCount: 15,
// itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
// if (index == 0) {
// return SizedBox(height: 15.0);
// } else if (index == 5) {
// return SizedBox(height: 100.0);
// }
// return Container(
// alignment: Alignment.center,
class _SettingsMenuState extends State<SettingsMenu> with ChangeNotifier {
  // int _inc = 0;
  bool _enabled;
  bool _icymistEnable = true;
  bool _heartEnable = true;
  bool _deepoceanEnable = true;
  bool _flowerEnable = true;
  bool _gardenEnable = true;
  bool _paradiseEnable = true;
  bool _midnightparadisEnable = true;
  bool _midnightEnable = true;
  bool _icymistSwitch = false;
  bool _icymistColor = false;
  bool _heartColor = false;
  bool _heartSwitch = false;
  bool _deepoceanSwitch = false;
  bool _deepoceanColor = false;
  bool _flowerColor = false;
  bool _flowerSwitch = false;
  bool _gardenSwitch = false;
  bool _gardenColor = false;
  bool _paradiseColor = false;
  bool _paradiseSwitch = false;
  bool _midnightparadiseSwitch = false;
  bool _midnightparadiseColor = false;
  bool _midnightColor = false;
  bool _midnightSwitch = false;
  String image1 = "test/assets/Para 1 - Alif-laam-meem no color/quranpg2-1.png";
  bool _showPreview = false;
  String _image =
      "test/assets/Para 1 - Color - Alif Laam Meem/pg2_bonus_cool_ice10x___2.png";
  // changeValue(bool value) {
  //   setState(() {
  //     _inc++;
  //     _value = value;
  //   });
  // }

  onpress() {
    GestureDetector(
        onLongPress: () {
          print("longpress");
        },
        onLongPressUp: () {
          print("longpressup");
        },
        child: Card());
  }

  changetoIcyMistImage() {
    // setState(() {
    return GestureDetector(onLongPress: () {
      setState(() {
        _showPreview = true;
        _image =
            "test/assets/Para 1 - Color - Alif Laam Meem/pg2_bonus_cool_ice10x___2.png";
      });
    });
  }
  // );

  trythis() {
    setState(() {
      RepaintBoundary(
          key: PeekAndPopMisc.background,
          child: MaterialApp(
              title: 'Peek & Pop Demo',
              home: MyHomePage(title: 'Peek & Pop Demo')));
    });
  }

  activateIcyMistHighlighter() {
    setState(() {
      _icymistColor = true;
      _icymistSwitch = true;
      _icymistEnable = true;
      _heartColor = false;
      _heartSwitch = false;
      // _heartEnable = !_heartEnable;
      _heartEnable = true;
      _deepoceanColor = false;
      _deepoceanSwitch = false;
      _deepoceanEnable = true;
      // _deepoceanEnable = !_deepoceanEnable;
      _flowerColor = false;
      _flowerSwitch = false;
      _flowerEnable = true;
      // _flowerEnable = !_flowerEnable;
      _gardenColor = false;
      _gardenSwitch = false;
      _gardenEnable = true;
      // _gardenEnable = !_gardenEnable;
      _paradiseColor = false;
      _paradiseSwitch = false;
      _paradiseEnable = true;
      // _paradiseEnable = !_paradiseEnable;
      _midnightparadiseColor = false;
      _midnightparadiseSwitch = false;
      _midnightparadisEnable = true;
      // _midnightparadisEnable = !_midnightparadisEnable;
      _midnightColor = false;
      _midnightEnable = true;
      // _midnightEnable = !_midnightEnable;
      _midnightSwitch = false;
      // notifyListeners();
    });
  }

  activateHeartHighlighter(bool value) {
    setState(() {
      _heartColor = true;
      _heartSwitch = true;
      _heartEnable = true;
      _icymistColor = false;
      _icymistSwitch = false;
      _icymistEnable = true;
      _deepoceanColor = false;
      _deepoceanSwitch = false;
      _deepoceanEnable = true;
      _flowerColor = false;
      _flowerSwitch = false;
      _flowerEnable = true;
      _gardenColor = false;
      _gardenSwitch = false;
      _gardenEnable = true;
      _paradiseColor = false;
      _paradiseSwitch = false;
      _paradiseEnable = true;
      _midnightparadiseColor = false;
      _midnightparadiseSwitch = false;
      _midnightparadisEnable = true;
      _midnightColor = false;
      _midnightEnable = true;
      _midnightSwitch = false;
      notifyListeners();
      // if (activateIcyMistHighlighter(value)) {
      //   setState(() {
      //     // _heartColor = false;
      //   });
    }
        // }
        );
  }
  // }

  activateDeepOceanHighlighter(bool value) {
    setState(() {
      _deepoceanColor = true;
      _deepoceanSwitch = true;
      _deepoceanEnable = true;
      _heartColor = false;
      _heartSwitch = false;
      _heartEnable = true;
      _icymistColor = false;
      _icymistSwitch = false;
      _icymistEnable = true;
      _flowerColor = false;
      _flowerSwitch = false;
      _flowerEnable = true;
      _gardenColor = false;
      _gardenSwitch = false;
      _gardenEnable = true;
      _paradiseColor = false;
      _paradiseSwitch = false;
      _paradiseEnable = true;
      _midnightparadiseColor = false;
      _midnightparadiseSwitch = false;
      _midnightparadisEnable = true;
      _midnightColor = false;
      _midnightEnable = true;
      _midnightSwitch = false;
    });
  }

  activateFlowerHighlighter(bool value) {
    setState(() {
      _flowerColor = true;
      _flowerSwitch = true;
      _flowerEnable = true;
      _heartColor = false;
      _heartSwitch = false;
      _heartEnable = true;
      _icymistColor = false;
      _icymistSwitch = false;
      _icymistEnable = true;
      _deepoceanColor = false;
      _deepoceanSwitch = false;
      _deepoceanEnable = true;
      _gardenColor = false;
      _gardenSwitch = false;
      _gardenEnable = true;
      _paradiseColor = false;
      _paradiseSwitch = false;
      _paradiseEnable = true;
      _midnightparadiseColor = false;
      _midnightparadiseSwitch = false;
      _midnightparadisEnable = true;
      _midnightColor = false;
      _midnightEnable = true;
      _midnightSwitch = false;
    });
  }

  activateGardenHighlighter(bool value) {
    setState(() {
      _gardenColor = true;
      _gardenSwitch = true;
      _gardenEnable = true;
      _flowerColor = false;
      _flowerSwitch = false;
      _flowerEnable = true;
      _heartColor = false;
      _heartSwitch = false;
      _heartEnable = true;
      _icymistColor = false;
      _icymistSwitch = false;
      _icymistEnable = true;
      _deepoceanColor = false;
      _deepoceanSwitch = false;
      _deepoceanEnable = true;
      _paradiseColor = false;
      _paradiseSwitch = false;
      _paradiseEnable = true;
      _midnightparadiseColor = false;
      _midnightparadiseSwitch = false;
      _midnightparadisEnable = true;
      _midnightColor = false;
      _midnightEnable = true;
      _midnightSwitch = false;
    });
  }

  activateParadiseHighlighter(bool value) {
    setState(() {
      _paradiseColor = true;
      _paradiseSwitch = true;
      _paradiseEnable = true;
      _flowerColor = false;
      _flowerSwitch = false;
      _flowerEnable = true;
      _heartColor = false;
      _heartSwitch = false;
      _heartEnable = true;
      _icymistColor = false;
      _icymistSwitch = false;
      _icymistEnable = true;
      _deepoceanColor = false;
      _deepoceanSwitch = false;
      _deepoceanEnable = true;
      _gardenColor = false;
      _gardenSwitch = false;
      _gardenEnable = true;
      _midnightparadiseColor = false;
      _midnightparadiseSwitch = false;
      _midnightparadisEnable = true;
      _midnightColor = false;
      _midnightEnable = true;
      _midnightSwitch = false;
    });
  }

  activateMidnightParadiseHighlighter(bool value) {
    setState(() {
      _midnightparadiseColor = true;
      _midnightparadiseSwitch = true;
      _midnightparadisEnable = true;
      _paradiseColor = false;
      _paradiseSwitch = false;
      _paradiseEnable = true;
      _flowerColor = false;
      _flowerSwitch = false;
      _flowerEnable = true;
      _heartColor = false;
      _heartSwitch = false;
      _heartEnable = true;
      _icymistColor = false;
      _icymistSwitch = false;
      _icymistEnable = true;
      _deepoceanColor = false;
      _deepoceanSwitch = false;
      _deepoceanEnable = true;
      _gardenColor = false;
      _gardenSwitch = false;
      _gardenEnable = true;
      _midnightColor = false;
      _midnightEnable = true;
      _midnightSwitch = false;
    });
  }

  activateMidnightHighlighter(bool value) {
    setState(() {
      _midnightColor = true;
      _midnightSwitch = true;
      _midnightEnable = true;
      _midnightparadiseColor = false;
      _midnightparadiseSwitch = false;
      _midnightparadisEnable = true;
      _paradiseColor = false;
      _paradiseSwitch = false;
      _paradiseEnable = true;
      _flowerColor = false;
      _flowerSwitch = false;
      _flowerEnable = true;
      _gardenColor = false;
      _gardenSwitch = false;
      _gardenEnable = true;
      _heartColor = false;
      _heartSwitch = false;
      _heartEnable = true;
      _icymistColor = false;
      _icymistSwitch = false;
      _icymistEnable = true;
      _deepoceanColor = false;
      _deepoceanSwitch = false;
      _deepoceanEnable = true;
    });
  }

  getColor(bool enabled) {
    if (_enabled == true) {
      return Colors.blue;
    } else {
      return Colors.purple;
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    ///
    return Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        // Color(0xFFFAFAFA),
        appBar: AppBar(
            backgroundColor: Colors.cyan,
            title: Text("Settings Menu",
                style: TextStyle(color: styling.appBarTextcolor)),
            leading: FlatButton(
                textColor: Colors.white,
                child: Icon(styling.appBarBackArrowIcon),
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.pop(context, false);
                  // WillPopScope(
                  //   onWillPop: () async {
                  //     // You can await in the calling widget for my_value and handle when complete.
                  //     Navigator.pop(context, 'my_value');
                  //     return false;
                  // },
                  // );

                  // Navigator.push(
                  //     context,
                  //     MaterialPageRoute(
                  //       builder: (context) => NavDrawer(),
                  //     ));
                }),
            actions: <Widget>[
              FlatButton(
                textColor: Colors.white,
                child: Text(
                  'Help',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 16.0,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  ),
                ),
                onPressed: () => print('Help'),
              )
            ]),
        body: new SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Container(
                constraints: BoxConstraints.expand(
                  // BoxConstraints
                  // BoxConstraints.expand(
                  height: 1200,

                  // .expand(
                  // width: SizeConfig.screenWidth / 0.5,
                  // height: SizeConfig.screenHeight / 0.5,
                ),

                // children: [
                child: Column(
                    // mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      // const SizedBox(
                      //   height: 5.0,
                      //   width: 10.0,
                      // ),

                      Text(
                        "English Highlighter Selection:",
                        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                        style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.white,
                          backgroundColor: Colors.cyan,
                          fontSize: 20.0,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        ),
                      ),
                      Divider(
                        color: Colors.black,
                      ),
                      // );
                      // }
// }
                      ListTile(
                          leading: Icon(
                            Icons.highlight,
                            color: Colors.cyan,
                          ),
                          tileColor:
                              _icymistColor ? Colors.cyan : Colors.transparent,
                          title: Text("Icy Mist"),
                          enabled: _icymistEnable,
                          subtitle: Text(
                              "A nice cooling Triple Gradient light blue highlighter with Teal and a hint of white"),
                          trailing: Icon(Icons.view_compact),

                          // onLongPress: changetoIcyMistImage()
//  return GestureDetector(
//               onLongPress: () {
//                 setState(() {
//                   _showPreview = true;
//                   _image = "assets/images/${images[index]}";
//                 });
//               },
//               onLongPressEnd: (details) {
//                 setState(() {
//                   _showPreview = false;
//                 });
//               },
//               child: Padding(
//                 padding: const EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
//                 child: Card(
//                   elevation: 4,
//                   shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
//                     borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0),
//                   ),
//                   clipBehavior: Clip.hardEdge,
//                   child: Image.asset("assets/images/${images[index]}"),
//                 ),
//               ),
//             );
//           },
//         ),
//         if (_showPreview) ...[
//           BackdropFilter(
//             filter: ImageFilter.blur(
//               sigmaX: 5.0,
//               sigmaY: 5.0,
//             ),
//             child: Container(
//               color: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.6),
//             ),
//           ),
//           Container(
//             child: Center(
//               child: ClipRRect(
//                 borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
//                 child: Image.asset(
//                   _image,
//                   height: 300,
//                   width: 300,
//                 ),

                          onTap: () {
                            onpress();
                          }
                          //   setState(() {
                          //     _showPreview = true;
                          //     _image =
                          //         "test/assets/Para 1 - Color - Alif Laam Meem/pg2_bonus_cool_ice10x___2.png";
                          //   });
                          // },

                          // onLongPressEnd: (details) {
                          //   setState(() {
                          //     _showPreview = false;
                          //   });
                          // },
                          // onTap: () {
                          //   // print("hey what is up");
                          //   changetoIcyMistImage();
                          // setState(() {
                          //   _color = !_color;
                          // });
                          // },
                          // ),
                          // }
                          ),
                      // ),
                      Switch(
                        // contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.all(0),
                        value: _icymistSwitch,
                        activeColor: Colors.cyan,
                        // title: Text("final one"),
                        onChanged: (bool value) => activateIcyMistHighlighter(),

                        // Center(
                        //   child: new Text("value ${_inc}"),
                        // ),

                        // ),
                      ),
                      Divider(
                        color: Colors.black,
                      ),
                      ListTile(
                        leading: Icon(
                          Icons.highlight,
                          color: Colors.red,
                        ),
                        enabled: _heartEnable,
                        tileColor:
                            _heartColor ? Colors.red : Colors.transparent,
                        title: Text("Heart"),
                        subtitle: Text(
                            "A Strong Hearty Double Gradient highlighter with a hint of black at the top"),
                        trailing: Icon(Icons.view_compact),
                        onTap: () {},
                      ),
                      Switch(
                          // contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.all(0),
                          value: _heartSwitch,
                          activeColor: Colors.red,
                          // title: Text("final one"),
                          onChanged: (bool _heartColor) =>
                              activateHeartHighlighter(_heartColor)),
                      // ),
                      Divider(
                        color: Colors.black,
                      ),
                      ListTile(
                        leading: Icon(
                          Icons.highlight,
                          color: Colors.blue,
                        ),
                        tileColor:
                            _deepoceanColor ? Colors.blue : Colors.transparent,
                        enabled: _deepoceanEnable,
                        // tileColor: Colors.transparent,
                        // getColor(!_enabled),
                        title: Text("Deep Ocean"),
                        subtitle: Text(
                            "Deep beneath the ocean comes this equisite Double Gradient highlighter with a hint of black"),
                        trailing: Icon(Icons.view_compact),
                        onTap: () {},
                      ),
                      Switch(
                          // contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.all(0),
                          value: _deepoceanSwitch,
                          activeColor: Colors.blue,
                          // title: Text("final one"),
                          onChanged: (bool _deepoceanColor) =>
                              activateDeepOceanHighlighter(_deepoceanColor)),
                      // ),
                      Divider(
                        color: Colors.black,
                      ),
                      ListTile(
                        leading: Icon(
                          Icons.highlight,
                          color: Colors.pink,
                        ),
                        enabled: _flowerEnable,
                        tileColor:
                            _flowerColor ? Colors.pink : Colors.transparent,
                        title: Text("Flower"),
                        subtitle: Text(
                            "A bright Fuschia Flower highlighter that has a perfect shade of dark and light"),
                        trailing: Icon(Icons.view_compact),
                        onTap: () {},
                      ),
                      Switch(
                          // contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.all(0),
                          value: _flowerSwitch,
                          activeColor: Colors.pink,
                          // title: Text("final one"),
                          onChanged: (bool _flowerColor) =>
                              activateFlowerHighlighter(_flowerColor)),
                      // ),
                      Divider(
                        color: Colors.black,
                      ),
                      ListTile(
                        leading: Icon(
                          Icons.highlight,
                          color: Colors.green,
                        ),
                        enabled: _gardenEnable,
                        tileColor:
                            _gardenColor ? Colors.green : Colors.transparent,
                        title: Text("Garden"),
                        subtitle: Text(
                            "A Foresty Green highlighter with a Double Gradient shade of light and dark"),
                        trailing: Icon(Icons.view_compact),
                        onTap: () {},
                      ),
                      Switch(
                          // contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.all(0),
                          value: _gardenSwitch,
                          activeColor: Colors.green,
                          // title: Text("final one"),
                          onChanged: (bool _gardenColor) =>
                              activateGardenHighlighter(_gardenColor)),
                      // ),
                      Divider(
                        color: Colors.black,
                      ),
                      ListTile(
                        leading: Icon(
                          Icons.highlight,
                          color: Colors.teal,
                        ),
                        enabled: _paradiseEnable,
                        tileColor:
                            _paradiseColor ? Colors.teal : Colors.transparent,
                        title: Text("Paradise"),
                        subtitle: Text(
                            "A Nice cool Double Gradient Teal and skyBlue highligher which has ligh and dark shades"),
                        trailing: Icon(Icons.view_compact),
                        onTap: () {},
                      ),
                      Switch(
                          // contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.all(0),
                          value: _paradiseSwitch,
                          activeColor: Colors.teal,
                          // title: Text("final one"),
                          onChanged: (bool _paradiseColor) =>
                              activateParadiseHighlighter(_paradiseColor)),
                      // ),
                      Divider(
                        color: Colors.black,
                      ),
                      ListTile(
                        leading: Icon(Icons.highlight,
                            color: Colors.purpleAccent[700]),
                        enabled: _midnightparadisEnable,
                        tileColor: _midnightparadiseColor
                            ? Colors.tealAccent
                            : Colors.transparent,
                        title: Text("Midnight Paradise"),
                        subtitle: Text(
                            "Most Exquisite to the eyes top with a nice Purple Midnight shade and the bottom with a Light Paradise light teal highlight"),
                        trailing: Icon(Icons.view_compact),
                        onTap: () {},
                      ),
                      Switch(
                          // contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.all(0),
                          value: _midnightparadiseSwitch,
                          activeColor: Colors.tealAccent,
                          // title: Text("final one"),
                          onChanged: (bool _midnightparadiseColor) =>
                              activateMidnightParadiseHighlighter(
                                  _midnightparadiseColor)),
                      // ),
                      Divider(
                        color: Colors.black,
                      ),
                      ListTile(
                        leading: Icon(
                          Icons.highlight,
                          color: Colors.purple,
                        ),
                        enabled: _midnightEnable,
                        tileColor:
                            _midnightColor ? Colors.purple : Colors.transparent,
                        title: Text("Midnight"),
                        subtitle: Text(
                            "The night so dim the Midnight shade of purple mixed with a dark night highlighter"),
                        // tileColor: Colors.,
                        trailing: Icon(Icons.view_compact),
                        onTap: () {},
                      ),
                      Switch(
                          // contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.all(0),
                          value: _midnightSwitch,
                          activeColor: Colors.purple,
                          // title: Text("final one"),
                          onChanged: (bool _midnightColor) =>
                              activateMidnightHighlighter(_midnightColor)),
                      // ),
                      Divider(
                        color: Colors.black,
                      ),
                    ]))));
  }
}
```

Comment: This could be solved using state management with flutter: https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/options . Also, setting the value in `SharedPreferences` will work but that will save the value in the app's storage. If all you have to do is save the value even if back button is pressed, you're better off with state management.

Answer (score 4):

try to define global variables if u want that in entire app but it will get lost once the user close the app.

the best way is to store that bool value in database like `shared_preferences` or 'hive`
. Here is the doc of https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences and https://pub.dev/packages/hive resp

```
SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
await prefs.setBool('switch', true);
```

for getting bool value

```
bool counter = prefs.getBool('switch') ?? false;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to store the values only for one session, you could use static members of a class, like this:

```
class Values{
  static List<bool> checkBoxValues = [false, false...];
}
```

If you want to save settings, you will have to use `shared_preferences`:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
await prefs.setBool('switch', true);
```

To get a value from anywhere in the program, use
prefs.getBool('switch')

Comment: can you please make it relative to my code ...  and also the second question of how to what ever switch is turned on that's the color image I want to display in another class ....

Comment: can you please use my code and explain it ... I tried and I am not getting it ... and the second question is more if and else statements that if the switch icy mist is enabled in the settings menu than display this image ... I need that code also ... I am not satisfied with both answers please that's lot of my own rep points and I need this ...

Comment: I have tried everything - please see where I am going wrong -   bool _icymistSwitch = false;   SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;   activateIcyMistHighlighter(bool) async {
    sharedPreferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    setState(() {
      // checkValue = true;
      _icymistSwitch = bool;
      sharedPreferences.setBool("Switch", true);getCredential() async {
    sharedPreferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    setState(() {
      _icymistSwitch = sharedPreferences.getBool("Switch");
      if (_icymistSwitch != null) {
        print("we a

Comment: if (_icymistSwitch != null) {
        print("we are in the switch");
      } else {
        print("no switch");
        _icymistSwitch = false;
      }
    });
  }.    and in the switch I have -- >  Switch(

                        value: _icymistSwitch,

                        activeColor: Colors.cyan,
                  
                        onChanged: (bool) async =>
                            await activateIcyMistHighlighter(_icymistSwitch),

Comment: I did this code I am in green but still when I turn the switch to on and click back and click on settings menu again the switch is not turned on ... I used shared preference but its not working

Answer (score 0):

I'd prefer sending it back as bool data using the `Navigator` like:

```
Navigator.pop(context, true);
```

for more info, have a look at the [docs](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/navigation/returning-data)

Comment: How do I do it for this  Switch(
                        // contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.all(0),
                        // value: _icymistSwitch,
                        value: _icymistSwitch,

                        activeColor: Colors.cyan,
                        // title: Text("final one"),
                        onChanged:
                        Navigator.pop(context, true);
                         (bool) async =>
                            await activateIcyMistHighlighter(_icymistSwitch),
                        // SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.ge